# three.js Basic Scene not Loading

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create the basic scene but nothing is loading on my HTML page. I don't know where to get the three.js file that I need to place inside my js folder before I can reference it as instructed on the docs page ().

Please can someone explain how I can import this file and add it into my js folder?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could share some code to judge if this is an internal problem.

First of all, if you make references to local files, you'll need to [run things locally](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=run%20things%20locally%20three.js&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) running a local server (for instance I run python -m http.server, then access my files in the browser from localhost:8000).

The other problem could be that your version of three.js or three.min.js is not the good one, you can actually get them from the [github build folder](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/build), and place them in the same repo as your html file, to be able to import them (`<script type="text/javascript" src="three.min.js"></script>`).

Finally, you could also see what's going wrong in your console if you work on Firefox for instance, it might help you to solve your error.

Comment: Thanks, Your second option helped solve my issue, everything is working properly now.